# How to remove spacific values from url string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have this URL string:

```
http://jackson/search/page/3/?features=Sea%20View&submit=search
```

Now I want to remove this part from ul: `page/3/` when page is reload.

I am not good with jQuery and regex so I will appreciate if you help me.

**Note: Page number can be anything form 1 to 100.**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your tried using `String.replace()`

```
var url = "http://jackson/search/page/3/?features=Sea%20View&submit=search";
url = url.replace(/page\/\d+\//, '');
```

Comment: `Page number can be anything form 1 to 100.`

Comment: @Praveen Thanks for the great help. I like it :)

Answer (score 1):

`\d` match any digit character:

```
url = 'http://jackson/search/page/3/?features=Sea%20View&submit=search';
url.replace(/page\/\d+\//, '')
// => "http://jackson/search/?features=Sea%20View&submit=search"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this,

```
var a='http://jackson/search/page/3/?features=Sea%20View&submit=search'.split('/');
console.log(a.slice(0,4).join('/')+'/'+a.slice(6).join('/'));
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/MbLmZ/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Javascript:

```
if (location.href.indexOf("/page/") > -1) {
   location.assign(location.href.replace(/\/page\/\d+\//, "/"));
}
```